# Non-fair die - College Probability

Tags: probability, self-study, inference, density-function, dice

How many times must you roll a non-fair die to be at least 84% sure that the sample probability will be within 3% from the actual probability.

Since the die is not-fair, we do not know p. My question is, can I assume it to be around 1/6, or not?

And so far, I found the Z-scores for 84% of the probability from the mean to be + & - 1.4. But, I do not know how to move forward with an unknown probability.

Comment: Could you address which of the concepts is tripping you up instead of just posing the question directly?

Comment: We need more information! Roll again!

Comment: @kyle. This is for a midterm I have later today.. It seems quite a bit ambiguous, but that is how it's been stated.

Comment: @RAF Thanks for the edits to your question. I think, since this is a homework problem, people wanted to help you with the underlying concepts, rather than just answer the question, which will help you more on your midterm anyway!

Comment: @kyle. Thanks a lot! Supposedly, it is a "Sample Question," but I wouldn't be surprised if the professor made a mistake either. I just believe that there isn't enough information to solve it.

Comment: @Glen_b What do you think now?

Comment: @RAF That was my initial reaction as well...it seems like you'd need to know in what way/to what extent the die is unfair.

Comment: The maximum value of the variance of the value obtained from a die roll is $(6-1)^2/4$ and occurs when the die is so biased that only a $1$ and a $6$ show up (with equal probability $\frac{1}{2}$) and $2,3,4,5$ never show up. Work out a $z$-score from this and determine the number of rolls needed. This will be an upper bound on the actual number of rolls needed with a die that is less strongly biased.

Comment: @Dilip That's a key idea. I wonder, though, whether there is *any* relationship intended between the *values* on the faces and the (extremely vague) "sample probability" of the question. The only reasonable interpretation of "sample probability" I can make is "sample *frequency*" and to me that sounds like it has to be a multinomial frequency.

Comment: @whuber Actually, now that I think of it, my comment does not apply if one wants to estimate _all_ the $6$ unequal probabilities to within a _relative_ error of $3$%. If one face has _small_ probability, say $10^{-4}$, then it will take a _long time_ before we can estimate this within $0.000097$ and $0.000103$ with any degree of confidence while the larger probabilities would have been estimated quite accurately very soon.

Answer (score 2):

As others say in the comments, the question makes no sense because it does not state the probability of what.  The probability of the die falling to a surface is presumably one, for example, regardless of how loaded it is.  I will assume it means the probability of rolling a six (I know this is by no means the only possibile interpretation of this ambiguous question).

The wording of the question asks for you to be "at least 84% sure that the sample probability will be within 3% from the actual probability."  The "at least" is surely significant.  You can answer the question by assuming the worst case scenario - the die is loaded so six shows up 50 percent of the time so the variance of the number of sixes is $n(\frac{1}{2})^2$.  Solve from there using usual methods.

So my answer is no, you cannot assume p is 1/6.  As you have been asked to be conservative ("at least") you must assume the worst case scenario, which is p=1/2.